# ImportError: No module named ... after spyder install

Tags: python, numpy, installation, anaconda, spyder

Anaconda Spyder is supposed to include numpy, scipy etc with the installation. Someone has installed Spyder for me on Windows 7 but if I try to `import numpy` or `scipy` , I get this error:

```
import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

I also can't run "conda" on the console.

What's wrong? What should I do to fix this? I tried adding `PYTHONPATH` in environment variables but no difference.

How can I check if they're even installed? I searched for NumPy in the computer, I only found the following:

[image]

Comment: One of the files you found is the installer of numpy is the third in your image. Try run it and let us know later.

Comment: I tried and got the following message: Python version 2.7 required, which was not found in the registry.

Comment: Mmmmmm, the thing is you have to install python 2.7. Surely you have a different python installed. If you download and install Python 2.7 this should works.

Comment: When you say "someone installed spyder for you" to you mean separately from the Anaconda spyder? The Spyder that comes with Anaconda (`conda install spyder`) should have access to all the Anaconda Python packages.

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't aware that Spyder is something independent from Anaconda!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like someone installed just spyder, not Anaconda, which is a separate thing (Anaconda is a collection of several Python packages, including Spyder, NumPy, and SciPy). Try downloading and installing [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads) and using the Spyder that comes with that.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you have to install python 2.7. Surely you have a different python installed. If you download and install Python 2.7 this should works. Other thing you can do is search for the **Anaconda Spyder** version that support the Python you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably that your the python core version of your spyder environment is different from the conda python version.

Python core version of your spyder environment

[image: 1]

Conda python version

[image: 2]

So you should make them of the same version then the problem will be solved.